# Why is My Image Not Showing Up in The Background?

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I am currently building a website and ran into a issue with my code. I am trying to set an image as a background for my header. I have checked the path to my image, the spelling of everything, and have checked my syntax online. Everything seems to match, so I don't understand why my image is not popping up. Any help you guys can give would be amazing. Thank you. Below is my css code:

```
header {                                                                                          
  text-align: center;                                                                                           
  background-image: url("image/concert.jpg");
  background-size: 700px;
  height: 333px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: must be the filepath, I guess - CSS seems okay - at least sufficient to display part of  a background-image

Comment: Check your browser development tools console, is there an error? Do the other CSS properties for the style block get applied?

Comment: You are using a `<header>` element, right, and not a `<div class='header'>` element?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have double checked the file path and everything looks good there. I still can’t get the image to pop-up though. Every other CSS property in the file gets applied and works. I am also using the <header> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what other people already commented on your question, it is worth noting that the filepath must be relative to the css file's location.
Say your entire project is in a folder named root, and css is located in `root/css/styles.css` but image is in `root/image/concert.jpg`, then, from your stylesheet, you should call the image like `background-image: url("../image/concert.jpg");`
Like @David Alsbright said, you should check the development tools console of your browser. It will help you determine if there's a problem with the file path.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'd appreciate it if you could mark the answer as the accepted one =)

Comment: Not a problem, I marked it! Sorry I forgot to at first